# Access Core Data from extension without provisioning profile on macOS?

Tags: core-data, quicklook, code-signing-entitlements

I'd like to add a Quick Look extension to my program, but in order to be useful, it would have to access the Core Data stack, which seems to require me to add an App Group and a provisioning profile to the project.

Until now, it has been possible for anyone to [download the project from Github](https://github.com/angstsmurf/spatterlight) and compile and run it out of the box. All project targets are set to Team: None and Sign to Run Locally. If I add my provisioning profile to the project, this will no longer work. They will have to create and add their own provisioning profile and change the Signing & Capabilities settings on each of the 26 targets (there seems to be no way to do them all at once). And the profile will have to be renewed every year.

My question is, is there any way around this? Is such a major change really necessary for what amounts to accessing a file inside the program's own bundle (and another in its Application Support folder?)

EDIT: As was pointed out to me [on the Apple Developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/672554?answerId=659947022#659947022), you don't need a provisioning profile as long as you prefix the group name with the development team identifier. This still won't make it build out of the box, though. You will still need a developer account and set a team on every target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed that you are supposed to have a team identifier as the prefix for the group name. That still doesn't solve the problem that my project will no longer build out of the box for anyone who downloads it from Github, but it answers the question asked in the subject line.